# Как записать видео с веб-камеры и сохранить его в файл?

Tags: java, поиск-библиотек, видео, web-камера

Мне нужно создать программу, которая будет записывать видео со встроенной веб-камеры ноутбука и сохранять в файл. Какой библиотекой можно воспользоваться для этого?

Comment: JavaFx в помощь, можно вникнуть и за часик без проблемно написать простую прогу записывающую видео :)

Comment: https://www.google.com. => java get web camera video => Первая ссылка. На поиск потратил 12 сек. Вы же ждете ответа уже 11 часов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой *OpenCV*.

[Тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/719878/How-to-Use-OpenCV-with-Java-under-Eclipse-IDE) есть туториал.